How to exclude duplicated classes from a library which is added by the gradle dependency, in android?
I am developing an AR app using google sceneform library, I have added Sceneform library in the dependency, and also i have added google filament library version 1.21.1 as well.
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1'
implementation "com.google.android.filament:filamat-android:1.21.1" 

The app gradle syncs just fine. but when I run the app I get duplicate class error. I think it might be the conflicting of dependencies added.
after searching for a answer i learned there is a way to exclude conflicting classes/group/modules like this
dependencies {
    implementation (com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1) {
        exclude group: 'com.google....', module: '.....'
    }
}

or
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    configurations {
        all { 
            exclude group: "com.google....", module: "......"
        }
    }
}

but in my case i don't get what should i exactly exclude within the group property and within the module property inside the exclude block like this example.
configurations {
        all { // You should exclude one of them not both of them 
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-core-ui"
            exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-compat"
        }
    }

can anyone help me to get rid of below duplication class error which i should exactly mention within the group '....' property and the module '....' property.
This is the duplication classes error i got in the build output
A The option setting 'android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true' is deprecated. The current default is 'false'.It will be removed in version 9.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.You can resolve this warning in Android Studio via 'Refactor' > Migrate BuildConfig to Gradle Build Files'

:arModuleApp:mergeDebugJavaResource
  ! org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
  ! java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.filament.AndroidPlatform found in modules jetified-filament-android-1.17.1-runtime (com.google.ar.sceneform:filament-android:1.17.1) and jetified-filament-android-1.21.1-runtime (com.google.android.filament:filament-android:1.21.1)
  ! org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeNativeLibs Task$MergeNativeLibs TaskWorkAction
  ! com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfilament-jni.so' from inputs:
! :arModuleApp:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
! :arModuleApp:mergeDebugNativeLibs
! Duplicate class found


ss1 - https://i.sstatic.net/AJfpfar8.png
ss2 - https://i.sstatic.net/Z9ZCZimS.png
